# How to setup Cloudera Hadoop Cluster on EC2 - S3 or EBS Instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudera

How to setup Cloudera Hadoop Cluster on EC2 - S3 or EBS Instances? 
I have Cloudera Manager on one of the EC2 instance which has EBS Storage. When I start creating Hadoop Cluster from Cloudera Manager it starts creating new EC2 Instances as per the number of node you specify. It will request the Instance but the issue is it generates "Instance Store" Instances.

How can I provide my already existing instances which has EBS or S3 storage?

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is by design:

> Why does Cloudera Manager prefer instance store-backed over EBS-backed
>   AMIs? Although EBS volumes offer persistent storage, they are
>   network-attached and charge per I/O request, so they are not suitable
>   for Hadoop deployments. If you wish to experiment with EBS-backed
>   instances, you can always use a custom EBS AMI.

[source](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/03/how-to-create-a-cdh-cluster-on-amazon-ec2-via-cloudera-manager/)

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop provide way to read and write data on S3 and EBS both in case of EBS you just need to mount the disk on your instance and use it in hadoop.

But in case of S3 there will be some extra step to provide **Access key and Secrate key** to hadoop by using property **fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId and fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey** in core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml as mention below

```
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId</name>
    <value>Access Key</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey</name>
    <value>Secret key</value>
  </property>
```

Then after setting this one can do following:

```
hadoop fs -ls s3n://Bucket_Name/
```

And this will print the available folders in your S3 Bucket.